# Как шаблон html правильно вставить в сайт на PHP?

Tags: php, html

Сделала дизайн сайта в html, теперь не знаю, как правильней будет его поставить на сайт, написанный на php. Пыталась делить на блоки и вставлять include. И еще в html вставлять коды php. Не знаю, как будет лучше. Что вы можете посоветовать?

Answer (score 3):

В большинстве случаев у вас будет **файл(ы).php**, где располагается HTML и PHP содержимое.

Если на сайте используется CMS (система управления сайтом), то в них обычно бывают шаблоны, которые отвечают за вывод страниц (HTML+PHP).

А вот пример вставки:

```
<? echo "Hello, this is PHP" ?> Тут может идти обычный HTML <? echo "А тут снова вывод PHP" ?>
<? echo "<a href=\"http://yandex.ru/\">ya.ru</a> - а тут вначале выполняется PHP, который затем формирует HTML" ?>
```

А вообще не очень корректный вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

1. html text `<? print $text;?>` html text
2. html text `<? print"html text";?>` html text
3. html text `<?=$text?>` html text
4. `<? print "html text".$text;?>` html text
5. `<? print "html text".$text."html text";?>`

Еще есть многие способы. 
Заместь print можно использовать echo
html text - обычный текст

Answer (score 1):

- PHP:  `<?php $var='страничка';?>`
- HTML: `<H2> Я весёлая <?php echo $var;?> </H2>`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте любые MVC фреймворки. Например Smarty. Код будет "читабельный", а главное редактировать шаблон будет проще простого.

В любом случае, покажите код, чтобы можно было дать более конкретный совет.

Comment: Ну вот опять о_О

Comment: что опять? оО

Comment: <a href="http://hashcode.ru/questions/23630/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B-vs-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C">вопрос задавал по этому поводу</a> )

Answer (score 0):

Ни в коем случае не смешивайте логику с шаблоном и статикой... Используйте шаблонизаторы (smarty) или можно тырнуть из DLE...